# How do I add image and text in a single row in react-table?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, react-table

I want to put each image and text side by side in a single column with react table. I can add two text side by side each in a single column, like this:

```
 Header: "Name",
    id: "User",
    accessor: (d) => `${d.user} ${d.wallet}`,
```

But to add a picture and text side by side is what I'm unable to do. Here is what I tried but I got undefined for both data.

```
  {
    Header: "Name",
    id: "User",
    accessor: (d) => `${d.img} ${d.name}`,
    Cell: ({ row }) =>
      `<div> ${(<Image src={row[1].values.img} className="rounded-full" alt="user" height={40} width={40} />)} 
      <div>${row[2].values.name}</div>
      </div>`,
  },
```

Pls how do I add an image and text side by side side by side in a single column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way and it works.

```
  {
    Header: "User",
    id: "User",
    accessor: (d) => (
      <div className="inline-flex  space-x-4 ">
        <Image src={d.img} alt="user" className="rounded-full" height={50} width={50} />{" "}
        <p className="inline-flex mt-4 ">{d.name}</p>
      </div>
    ),
  },
```